# Change Color/Weight/Font of a Text dynamically in Rich Text

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have a special case where I have a paragraph and I need to make some words in paragraph bold.
I don't know the content as it will be changing. Is it possible to change the particular words' style based on a condition?
Example: the words I need to change color for are in between **||**

Live Example :
|Stack Overflow| is the largest, most trusted online community for |developers| to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers

Here I need to change the color of **Stack Overflow** and **developers**

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change some part of text you can use rich text, please check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rykDVh-QFfw

if you want to add condition to modefiy property follow this:

1- make you widget a `StateFullWidget`

2- using `(condtion) ? (do this if condition true) : (do this if condition false)`

i.e `color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,`

3- in the event you will start to change the poperty for it i.e `OnPressed()` using `setState((){ _isSelected = !_isSelected })` or any condition you want

Comment: I'm aware of these basics. I asked for the logic